# python convert nested data to array

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I want to convert original data to array , just like the second code block.

How to remove the dictionary key of the original data?

And how to convert dictionary to array?

```
original data:

result = {
    'Anna': [{
            'Name': 'Anna',
            'city': 'LA',
            'activity': 'run'
        },{
            'Name': 'Anna',
            'city': 'NY',
            'activity': 'sing'
        }
    ],
    'Ken': [{
            'Name': 'Ken',
            'city': 'JP',
            'activity': 'ride'
        },{
            'Name': 'Ken',
            'city': 'WA',
            'activity': 'climb'
        }
    ]
}
```

```
result = [   
        {
            'Name': 'Anna',
            'city': 'LA',
            'activity': 'run'
        },{
            'Name': 'Anna',
            'city': 'NY',
            'activity': 'sing'
        },{
            'Name': 'Ken',
            'city': 'JP',
            'activity': 'ride'
        },
            .
            .
            .
    ]
```

Comment: Can you show some code that you've already tried, and where you're stuck?

Comment: What have you tried? Post your code first or we can't help you

Comment: `[*itertools.chain.from_iterable(result.values())]`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(result.values()))` is more readable and possibly slightly more efficient.

Comment: @Błotosmętek not sure about efficiency, although `list(...)` version is portable across Python versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like doing nested list comprehensions. The following iterates first over all values in your dictionary (a list called `x`) and then over each element `i` in the list `x`.

```
[i for x in result.values() for i in x]
```